# Android App getting kicked off from device

Tags: android, mobile

I have developed an app which does some content processing in background continuously. The app is compatible in  Android 6,7,8. The memory CPU usage of the app is just 6%. When run the app in Samsung - Android version 8.1 it runs fine continuously but in OPPO Android 8.1 the app is getting kicked off. I don't see any errors in the logcat or any app crash. Any ideas around the issue - why it happens, how to debug the root cause etc will be very helpful.

Comment: you should add stacktrace

Comment: Is it killed or just suspended? I guess, manufacturers have a lot of possibilities to fine tune stuff like that. Also energy management has gotte a whole lot more aggressive i  newer android versions. If you feel secure enough, maybe try configuring the balancer or other scheduler/low level settings in the developer settings.

Comment: Use a [foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground).

Comment: @greeble31 Exactly I am using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService . currently I am starting it as bounded service with bindService(..) . As per Android 8 bounded services needed be bought to foreground.

Comment: @androiddeveloper "As per Android 8 bounded services needed be bought to foreground" <-- I'm not sure what you mean by that. However, if you say that you are calling `startForeground()`, and your notification icon is present in the status bar at the time this bug takes place, then we can be satisfied you've done it correctly.